# Hindu deities and nearby cultures

Tags: history, book-recommendation

Mitra is supposed to have got transformed to Mithra. It also made into Zoroastrianism. Sun seems to widely popular deity in ancient cultures. Is there any good book that relates Hindu Culture and other ancient cultures?

Comment: you might try Joseph Campbell especially his book 'The Myth of the Hero' and Mircea Elaide's 'Patterns in Comparative Religion'

Answer (score 2):

You can try to read:

- [Some Missing Chapters of World History by P.N. Oak](https://www.indiadivine.org/content/files/file/461-some-missing-chapters-of-world-history-by-pn-oak-pdf/)

I don't know whether this book is 100% authentic or the author creating histories as he go along.